# Wash sale clarification on options trading

Tags: united-states, options, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

If I buy deep in-the-money put options, and sell not so deep in-the-money (higher strike priced) put options and if both expire worthless, will I not be allowed to deduct the loss incurred from the first set from the gains accrued on the second since the two sets might be considered as "substantially identical securities"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long put is not substantially identical to a  short put so there could be no wash sale.

To trigger a wash sale, one would have to acquire a substantially identical security within 30 days before or 30 days after realizing a loss on one (or both) of these securities.

Comment: Isn't a long put on stock ABC like selling stock ABC and a short put on stock ABC like buying stock ABC?

Comment: That is true but they are not substantially identical (SI).  Selling a deep ITM put would be SI to long stock but IRS rules are not clear on how deep is deep enough.

Comment: So does one leave it to the broker decide whether the wash sale rule applies? I don't see much scope to challenge them should they decide to apply the rule.

Comment: Broker's don't get to randomly choose if it's a wash sale or not.  Their computer programs do the calculations.  If they make a mistake, you can challenge it.  They're not infallible.

Comment: I see considerable subjectivity in the way "substantially identical" could be interpreted. That's why I felt what I did. In any case, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think you're correct that there is considerable subjectivity in the way "substantially identical" could be interpreted. I would guess that brokers might be utilizing some universally software for this but that's just a hunch.  IRS code is clearly not straightforward and only and audit sets you straight.